# Why inserting 0 (zero) to Sql Server Auto Increment Field when inserting Fisrt Time

Tags: auto-increment

I go a big problem that when i am inserting First record to a table, that has one auto increment field. This field is accepting 0 (zero) when first time insert..
What is the problem. its making my program error

Comment: Fix the error in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your table to start auto increment from 1

```
ALTER TABLE whatevers AUTO_INCREMENT 1
```